# Cannot reference a field from currentItem in the new Collection Filter node

Tags: visual-workflow, loop, collection

I am trying to update a field on the triggering object using a Flow. I have filtered my options using a Collection Filter and it returns a single item. When I then try to assign it, it displays as a null value.

In the Filter Node:

```
Source collection: GetOwners
Create a collection, applying these filter conditions

All conditions must be true (AND)
1. {!currentItem_Filter_by_Discount.FF_Min__c} (null) Less than {!DiscountPercent} (20)
2. {!currentItem_Filter_by_Discount.FF_Max__c} (null) Greater than or equal {!DiscountPercent} (20)
Items in source collection: 1
Items in filtered target collection: 1
Result

[Owner_Approver__c=0053L0000017BiUQAU,FF_Max__c=20.0,Id=a1S3L000000ofg8UAA,FF_Min__c=10.0]
```

In the Assign Node:

```
{!$Record.Approver__c} Equals {!currentItem_Filter_by_Discount.Owner_Approver__c}
Result

{!$Record.Approver__c} = "null"
```

If I use a Loop, I receive an error message that the user cannot see this field.

```
Error Occurred:

The flow failed to access the value for LoopOwners.00N3L000001WU6V.Id because the field is not available to the running user.
```

What are my options here?

Comment: What's the context? What object, is it before or after update/create, what field are you updating? You'd want to loop through the new collection created by the Collection Filter (`records from Filter_by_Discount`). You do not want to use `currentItem_` as that's to be used within the Collection Filter formula condition.