# A Variable of the Collection Filter in Flows

Tags: visual-workflow

Inserting the new Collection Filter element (resp. FilterCollectionProcessor) (54.0) in a flow, one gets a new "Record Single Variable" that appears under Resources, per default with a name like "currentItem_MyElementName". As the name indicates: it's not a collection. It is available for input and output however, and it appears as a proper variable in the WSDL of the Metadata API. What is the importance of this variable?

The question is not regarding the collection used for referring to the filtered list - which is not a variable at all in terms of the Metadata API. Astonishingly for me, the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_filter.htm&type=5) states:

> A Collection Filter’s output collection is named after its API name. For example, if a Collection Filter element is named FilterLeads, its output collection is called CurrentItem_FilterLeads.

Maybe I've misunderstood something? Adding the variable e.g. in a RecordDelete later in the flow, I can activate the flow, but when run - "We hit a snag": "No records in Salesforce match your delete criteria." Better use the collection! (Maybe [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/370085/cannot-reference-a-field-from-currentitem-in-the-new-collection-filter-node) is related?!)

I'm facing generally difficulties to find documentation regarding flows. E.g. in the [documentation of the flow Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm), not only the above element, but all FlowCollectionProcessors seem absent. Is there a more exhaustive flow documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Unofficialsf](https://unofficialsf.com/sneak-preview-the-new-collection-filter-element/) has the following info in "additional usage notes" from its sneak preview written by VP of Product Management (covering Flow):

> The CurrentItem Variable Persists After Collection Filter is Removed
>
> When the new Filter Collection element is inserted into a flow, **a record variable called CurrentItem_FilterElementName is automatically generated and added to the flow to provide a way to use formulas and expressions for filtration.**
>
> If the Collection Filter element is deleted from the flow, the CurrentItem variable will be left as a resource in the flow and will need to be deleted manually.

As such, it's usage is to be leveraged when selecting `Formula Evaluates to True` within the "Condition Requirements" of the Collection Filter element.

[image]

That documentation you linked/quoted was *partially* correct, but the example given was incorrect as you've noted (*documentation has been updated*). The document now shows the correct naming

> For example, if a Collection Filter element is named FilterLeads, its output collection is called Leads from FilterLeads.

Comment: Cool, Kris! Thanks again - and I have more documentation to study now...!